# What affects the chance to get ambushed on Framing Frame Day 2?

Tags: payday-2

On Framing Frame Day 2, there is a chance that SWAT is going to ambush you after your painting trade. What affects this chance? Is it certainly going to happen in some cases? Is it ever certain that it doesn't happen?

To clarify; I'm talking about the actual objective "Ambushed" that happens as soon as you enter the warehouse:

[image: OBJECTIVE ACTIVATED: AMBUSHED - POLICE ASSAULT IN PROGRESS]

This is separate from the workers calling police. That might happen if you *don't* get ambushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen and heard a lot about this ambush.

From my experience, finishing the day one without triggering the alarm will insure you to avoid it.  [The wiki](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Framing_Frame) seems to confirm it:

> Note: If you have successfully completed Day 1 in stealth, you will not be ambushed on Day 2.

It also says that

> If you have not successfully completed Day 1 in stealth, there is a chance you will be ambushed though it is random, it is possible to go loud on Day 1 and have no ambush on Day 2 if you escape during the hostage phase.

I've also seen a guy putting an ECM jammer on the cell phone instead of answering it, before the second phone call.  He wasn't sure, but thought it would reduce the chances of an ambush.

Comment: I have been ambushed on day 2 after stealthing day 1 - I think this is also linked to the number of paintings you've collected from day 1.

Comment: Mhmm, ok, never happened to me (the 5 last times I played it, we made day 1 stealthy and escaped with 7 paintings). Then I suppose that either you experienced a bug, either stealthing day 1 only greatly decreases chances of an ambush on day 2... Yet just another obscure Payday random event...

Comment: @Anto - You might want to mention about the driving asset introduce in Update 11.  I wouldn't even mention the being ambushed after stealthing day 1, its not suppose to happen, the day 2 ambush is avoided by getting the 3 civs before the helicopter leaves.

Comment: Nope, the 3 civs are a different (additionnal) factor: they only call the police if you scare the birds when you enter the warehouse.  It's been made pretty clear in the question.

Comment: @kalina The wiki says that's a bug. But then again, it's wikia, so I'm a little skeptical. It would make sense for that to be the case though.

Comment: Yeah it would make sense to me that getting ambushed after stealthing day one is a bug, since if you stealthed day one nobody would even know you were there!

Comment: The only time I haven't been ambushed is when I had 7-8 paintings on normal mode (not sure if difficulty has anything to do with it but I figured I'd mention).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently avoiding the ambush is never guaranteed. I used to believe that it was 0% chance of ambush if you stealthed day 1, but yesterday proved that assumption wrong.

As someone who enjoys stealth, I've probably played Framing Frame more than any other mission in the game as it's a fun mission and decent xp & cash. I usually solo it until I've got a lock on day 3, as playing with randoms online almost always results in nearly immediate failure of stealth. Last night, an assault happened to me two times in a row after stealthing day 1. Both were pro jobs with a 3 skull "Overkill" difficulty. First time it happened I was solo, then after failing that on day 2 when a cloaker kicked me in the face then downed the AI teammates who tried to come help (dun dun dun), I joined a group of 3 others doing FF. In both instances, I sprinted out of the doors of the train car as soon as they opened trying to get to the construction workers & get them down but an assault popped as soon as I made it through the doors of the large building you have to run through. I also planted a jammer in both instances (an old habit from one playthrough where one of the construction workers had run down to the end of the street and I didn't find him to tie him up before he had called the police), but I've done that many times before and never had it result in an assault.

Long story short, it is possible to get an assault on day 2 after stealthing day 1. Seems a very small chance, but it absolutely can happen. I'd advise bringing at least one of your "loud" guns just in case even if you stealthed 1. Just don't forget to switch back for day 3!

-Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can still be ambushed after completing Day 1 stealthily, however there is a very small chance. I was pretty pissed because i was trying to solo the job and it was a pro job and then the ambush screwed me over.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I haven't even left the train and the civilians spot something suspicious and call the police. I think you really need to run out the train as quickly as possible with no bag and run as fast as you can to the three civilians and tie them up. Good luck.